# Bound on the moment of Schatten norm

Tags: probability, matrices, normed-spaces, matrix-norms, moment-problem

Let $A$ be a positive semidefinite matrix. Are there any bounds known for the $q$-th moment of the $p$-th Schatten norm of matrix $A$? Here, $1 \leq p,q \leq \infty$.